# Unknown return type in template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a function

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
/*return type*/ foo(MyClass<T1>& bar1, MyClass<T2>& bar2)
{
    if (something)
        return bar1;
    else
        return bar2;
}
```

The problem is, that I don't know what will this function return: it can be either `MyClass<T1>` or `MyClass<T2>`.

How can I get it to work?

T1 and T2 are structs of 3 ints, known at compile time. The return type depends on the *smaller* of those 2: for example for `T1 = <5, 1, 1>` `T2 = <4, 4, 7>` return type should be `MyClass<T2>`.

Example usage:

```
MyClass<5, 2, 8> m1;
MyClass<4, 2, 1> m2;
cout << foo(m1, m2); //should print m2 (I have a method used for that)
```

Comment: Is `something` a compile-time or runtime condition?

Comment: Yes good to know if it is compile time or runtime...

Comment: Edited to answer that question.

Comment: I have a feeling it's possible. If you can post example usages, it'll be helpful.

Comment: Are `T1` and `T2` types? Or do you mean: `MyClass<5,1,1>` and `MyClass<4,4,7>` and `T1` and `T2` are just placeholders for the three ints?

Comment: If you know it at compile time you can use some metaprogramming to find a place where the min is then map it to a type, so you don't need function for that.

Comment: I have added an example, hope it helps!

Comment: Of course, if instead of wanting to return one or the other you wrote a `print` function that took the two, selected one and called `std::cout << x` on that one, your life would be much easier...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas this is just an example, the function foo must work as described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define two functions from which only one will be instantiated for given types:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct ChooseFirst;

template <int A1, int B1, int C1, int A2, int B2, int C2>
struct ChooseFirst<MyClass<A1, B1, C1>, MyClass<A2, B2, C2>> {
    // this requires constexpr make_tuple (C++14)
    static const bool value = std::make_tuple(A1, B1, C1) < std::make_tuple(A2, B2, C2);
    // if in your implementation make_tuple is not constexpr, you can write the comparison manually:
    // static const bool value = A1 < A2 || (A1 == A2 && (B1 < B2 || (B1 == B2 && C1 < C2)));
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
typename std::enable_if<ChooseFirst<T1, T2>::value, T1&>::type foo(T1& bar1, T2&) {
    return bar1;
}

template <typename T1, typename T2>
typename std::enable_if<!ChooseFirst<T1, T2>::value, T2&>::type foo(T1&, T2& bar2) {
    return bar2;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a308b16a55095a65)

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to achieve there cannot be done as is. The language does not allow you to have a function that, based on some runtime data, changes its return type. Depending on the problem that you are trying to solve, there might be different alternatives, like determining a common type that can be used to represent either `bar1` or `bar2` or reorganizing the code so that you don't need to return at all.

That is if `something` cannot be determined at compile time... if it can be determined you can have some metaprogramming in place to determine the return type to be the one you need.

You should provide a higher level description of the real problem, after which you might get better ideas as of what direction to take.

---

You can try something in the lines of:

```
template <bool value> struct Bool {};

template <typename T, typename U>
T f_impl(T t, U u, Bool<true>) { return t; }
template <typename T, typename U>
T f_impl(T t, U u, Bool<false>) { return u; }

template <int A, int B, int C, int D, int E, int F>
auto f(MyClass<A,B,C> a, MyClass<D,E,F> b)
  -> f_impl(a, b, Bool<!(A < D 
                     || (A == D && B < E) 
                     || (A == D && B == E && C < F))>())
{
   return f_impl(a, b, Bool<!(A < D 
                          || (A == D && B < E) 
                          || (A == D && B == E && C < F))>());
}
```

Comment: I eddited question to provide more information on T1 and T2.

Comment: @MDo: Do you care about the value, or just the type that is returned? (i.e. what is really `MyClass`? Can different `MyClass<X,Y,Z>` hold different values for the same `X,Y,Z` tuple? The description *structs of 3 ints known at compile time* is not clear to me.

Comment: Yes, it can, but it is easy to set those using a constructor - if we knew which type we want to use, we could easily create an object to return.

Comment: You should really write down the template `MyClass`, it is not so clear... <strike>I will attempt a solution based on some vague understanding of what you are saying...</strike> No, not really. I don't think I understand what you could mean with *struct of 3 ints known at compile time*

Comment: I have added an example, hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to make a callback instead of returning value, remember tell don't ask principle:

```
template<typename T>
struct op{
  void operator ()(T t){}
};

template<>
struct op<int>{
  void operator ()(int a){}
};

template<typename T>
struct Func : public op<T>{
  int a;
};

template<typename T, typename T2>
void foo( Func<T> t, Func<T2> t2){
  t.a = 3;
  t2.a = 4;
  if( t.a > t2.a ){
    t( 3 );
  }else{
    t2( 5 );
  }
}
```

Maybe there is a better solution. Or you can use the operator () in MyClass, just specialize it.

Answer (score 1):

You could return a `union` type, that can either be `T1` or `T2`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the return type must be fixed as compile time, you must return something that can be either `MyClass<T1>` or `MyClass<T2>`. This could either be a generic object such as `boost::any` (a bit of an overkill for this situation) or a common base, a reference (or pointer) to which you then return. This requires your classes to be defined like

```
class MyClassBase { /* ... */ };
template<typename T>
class MyClass : MyClassBase {  /* ... */ };

template<typename T1, typename T2>
MyClassBase& foo(MyClass<T1>&bar1,MyClass<T2>&bar2)
{
    if (something)
        return bar1;
    else
        return bar2;
}
```

You can actually use RTTI so that the base `MyClassBase` can tell what it actually is. In fact, this is roughly how `boost::any` works.

---

Of course, as David said, if `something` is known at compile time, then your code is not really a good design and you should instead use a different one, using compile-time solutions (via template meta-programming techniques).

Answer (score 1):

Both bar1 and bar2 are references so they are both returned if you change them in some way in your function. You could use a return value to indicate which:

```
enum ReturnType
{
    BAR1,
    BAR2
}

ReturnType foo(MyClass<T1>& bar1, MyClass<T2>& bar2)
{
    if (something)
        return BAR1;
    else
        return BAR2;
}

int main()
{
    MyClass<T1> t1;
    MyClass<T2> t2;
    ReturnType ret = foo(t1, t2);
    if(ret == BAR1)
    {
        // do what you want in case of MyClass<T1>
    }
    else if(ret == BAR2)
    {
        // do what you want in case of MyClass<T2>
    }
}
```

An other way that maybe is closer to what you want is to use a base class pointer:

```
class Base
{
}

template<typename T>
class MyClass : public Base
{
     // ...
}

Base* foo(MyClass<T1>& bar1, MyClass<T2>& bar2)
{
    if (something)
        return &bar1;
    else
        return &bar2;
}
```

Just as mentioned by vsoftco in the comments and in Walters answer returning a reference works too if that is your preference.

```
Base& foo(MyClass<T1>& bar1, MyClass<T2>& bar2)
{
    if (something)
        return bar1;
    else
        return bar2;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't do it, as you don't really return the type `MyClass<T>`, but only an enum constant that marks which type you should have returned.

Comment: The updated edit should work, removed the -1. you could also just return a reference `Base&`

Comment: I added an other idea to consider and also how I intended for the original idea to be used. I know it isn't exactly what was asked but it is a work around since what is asked is not possible in c++